# understanding and modifying an include-search map command

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, normal-mode

I found a useful map at the include-search ([I) help.

```
map <leader>1 [I:let nr = input("Which one: ")<Bar>exe "normal " . nr ."[\t"<CR>
```

This opens the file found on the line I type (after [I displaying all assurances of current line).
I don't understand the syntax, I want to modify- opening the file in new tab.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Which parts of the syntax are confusing? It would be helpful to see your understanding so we can focus on the relevant parts.

Comment: Note, though, that the mapping is effectively `[I` followed by `<nr>[<Tab>` which is the same as `<nr>[<C-i>`. Near that help page, we can find `<C-w>i` for splitting and `:ijump` which allows more control. If you really want a new tab, try `:execute 'tab isplit' nr expand('<cword>')` or `execute 'normal!' nr."\<C-w>i\<C-w>T"`

Comment: Thanks , what is the expand(<cword>) and what is the ! after  normal?

Comment: Pro-tip: learn to use `:help` :) for example, `:help expand()` and `:help :normal` have the answers you are looking for.